# Where can I find sentiment based categorical dictionary?

Tags: dictionary, data-mining, sentiment-analysis

I want sentiment based category wise dictionary which categories words like fruits, vehicles, conjunctions, articles etc.

Dictionary which categorize negative and positive words are available easily but this I could not find out.

Comment: What is the sentiment of banana?!? I think you are mixing up terms, or quite unclear on what you want to achieve. **sentiment** analysis is not about fruit, but about **positive and negative emotions** ... that is why you only find positive and negative word lists.

Comment: @Anony-Mousse: I dont target only fruits. Doing sentiment analysis based on +ve and -ve words is one way. For domain specific sentiment analysis one may need sentiment dictionary for that domain. Suppose I want to exclude particular domain specific words from my analysis, then dont you thing this categorical clissfication will help me? There was no reason for down voting!

Comment: @Karimkhan for domain specific words you will have to generate a dictionary yourself. See my answer for how to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[AFINN-111](http://www2.imm.dtu.dk/pubdb/views/publication_details.php?id=6010) is the basic sentiment index but good luck trying to make a fruit happy. You can see the list [here](https://github.com/uwescience/datasci_course_materials/blob/master/assignment1/AFINN-111.txt).

One thing you can do is to append to AFINN-111 by giving banana +1 every time it appears in a sentence with a positive word, and -1 when it appears with a negative word. This way you can analyze if banana is showing up in more positive or negative context.

Comment: I am creating dynamic reference list for this purpose as you told but in little different way. I am classifying my words excluding unrelated word. Suppose particular word "mango" coming maximum time. So I can say articles is regarding fruit. But after having classified and I have particular word which appear max time, how can I decide to which category it belongs?

Comment: The answer could greatly vary depending on your application. Here is an article on document classification: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Text_classification